# Adding edge wear to (relatively) low-poly mesh

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, shaders, texture-painting

I'm working on modeling some objects, and I would like to add edge wear procedurally in cycles without being forced to use the pointiness node and messing around with subsurf issues (not using subsurf would help me worry more about the art, instead of just topology).  Is there any alternative to the pointiness node or manually painting in the edge mask in this situation?

Comment: There is one - Dirty Vertex Colors in Vertex paint mode. But it depends on topology just as well and is the same as Pointiness from this point of view. Other than that you can try Texture Paint > Toolshelf > Options tab > Cavity mask. it will depend on texture UV map and results might not be quite clear

Comment: There is a paid resource on blendermarket, as well as others that use very complex shader setups to get the effect of edgewear. Here is the link https://blendermarket.com/products/metalworks-passthrough-series-environmental-wear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new option I saw a [tweet](https://twitter.com/Linko_3D/status/930779389238882304) about today, and I can include the picture that was uploaded - it involves the experimental bevel shader. Maybe you can try that out.
[image: bevel shader to get edge wear]

Comment: Aw man, if that's real that would be awesome.  I'm still going to leave the question open until I can confirm that it's real.

Comment: It is real, but you have to get the bevel shader from trunk builds since it is after the 2.79 stable release.

Comment: I wanted to add that the bevel vector input is available in the latest "official" build of blender 2.79 from https://builder.blender.org.  This is the perfect option for me.

Comment: I know this is old but that doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. I figure you'd be better off doing the dot product (which is also cheaper) and a `map range` from <-1, 1> to <0, 1>.

Maybe he does something really smart with what he has there, but it gave me strange results and I can't really see the point.