# How to make that metall texture?

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, node-editor, shaders

im looking at that picture of a sci fi terminal and im wondering about how to make that kind of white-metall-look? Is that maybe handpainted?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82472/how-to-add-scratches and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21283/add-scratches-to-a-material-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94187/adding-edge-wear-to-relatively-low-poly-mesh and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120915/edge-angle-dependent-material-apply and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3337/procedurally-generating-wear-on-an-object and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55991/blurring-feathering-a-procedural-pointiness-mask/68958#68958

Comment: There is a lot of information already on this site on this topic. Use the search box at the top.

Comment: there's a guy who has made a nice Mask node, it might help to get the scratch on the edges: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSOMqOmnwEY